# Can custom ribbon buttons be active regardless of the context?

Tags: office-365, ribbon

We have a custom ribbon tab for an Office 365 environment. The buttons on the ribbon are always inactive until the user selects a document library.

Is it possible to define the custom ribbon tab so that the button status does not depend on selecting a document library? While the buttons do make changes to documents, the changes are not based on the concept of a "current library".